# Unable to push into gitlab as part of CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to modify the `package.json` for version string and committing as part of CI but `git push` is failing for me. Following is the code in `gitlab-ci.yml` in my stage:

```
before_script:
  - git remote set-url origin https://userid:${CI_PUSH_TOKEN}@gitlaburl.com/datastorage/project.git
  script:
  - call npm install gulp-json-modify --save
  - git checkout -B myBranch
  - call npm run modifyBuildVersion
  - git add package.json
  - git commit -m "[skip_ci]Automated commit from CI runner"
  - git push --follow-tags origin myBranch
```

Where CI_PUSH_TOKEN is an environment variable I created under settings->CI/CD and this key contains the value of personal access tokens.
In the step of git push I am getting an error

> "remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed for"

Any idea what's going wrong here?
I tried to search around but didn't get much help.

Comment: isn't it gitlab-ci-token: instead of userid:

Answer (score 0):

Did you give at least `developer` right for userid on your repo ?

If you use use the gitlab-ci-token as user, you are not able to push for the moment (in Gitlab 11.8). There is an open [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18106).

Comment: I am not giving gitlab-ci-token but my real user id using which I login into gitlab. Also I am maintainer on the repository.